# understanding the Knapsack problem O(2^n) where T(n)

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Question: With the best solution of knapsack being O(2^n), how fast would a partition function (below) be in terms on N?

Is this just as simple as saying O(n + 2^n)?
or is that just wrong and its O(2^n) since we now know what T(n) is.

partition function:

```
bool Partition(List S){  
     create two lists //O(n) + O(n) 
     M = (Sum of all elements in S)/2; //O(n) 
     K = (Sum of all elements in S)/2; //O(n)
     if(Knapsack(Profits, Weights, M, K) == true) // O(2^n) 
          return true; 
     else 
     return false; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity is just `O(2^n)` because a complexity of `O(n + 2^n)` is `O(2^n)`.